# Why is getElementsByTagName not finding elements?

Tags: xml, vba, dom

I'm new to processing XML documents and the Microsoft DOM so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

I have a set of documents in XML format that ultimately I want to edit programmatically.  As a discovery step, I'm trying to open a single one and seeing how to read its contents.

Following examples I found online, I've created a console project in Visual Studio 2019 and written a few lines of code.

The document contains 2 instances of the element "DataSource", but the method getElementsByTagName("DataSource") doesn't seem to find them.  Indeed, whatever tag I give the command, the length of the element array always comes back as 0.

What am I doing wrong?

MY XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily">
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="SharedDataSource">
      <DataSourceReference>QL_Copy</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>801777da-c111-4aa2-b8e9-49ba90f19774</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource Name="CustomDataSource">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>Data Source=v-citywsql03;Initial Catalog=BE</ConnectString>
        <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:SecurityType>Integrated</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>dcfb0e9c-06d9-4538-9ec6-1568b32daf3b</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <Height>2in</Height>
        <Style />
      </Body>
      <Width>6.5in</Width>
      <Page>
        <PageHeight>29.7cm</PageHeight>
        <PageWidth>21cm</PageWidth>
        <LeftMargin>2cm</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>2cm</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>2cm</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>2cm</BottomMargin>
        <ColumnSpacing>0.13cm</ColumnSpacing>
        <Style />
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>4</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>2</NumberOfRows>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Cm</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>f3bca84a-9587-4ba2-b1ed-57e31a33eb3b</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ReportFilename As String
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Dim xmlSourceList As Object

    ReportFilename = "C:Temp\Report1.xml"

    xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load(ReportFilename)

    xmlSourceList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DataSource")
    MsgBox(xmlSourceList.length)

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Visual Studio or VBA? Note that you have probably a type in the filename, you are missing a `\` after `C:`.

Comment: This is in Visual Studio 2019.  I tried coding it first in MS Access 2010 but I got a run-time error 424 every time at "Set xmlDoc.asynch = False", couldn't figure out what caused that, and wouldn't work when I took the line out, I guess because the rest of the code could execute before the document had loaded.

Comment: It works with MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0 if you trim off the header of your XML data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error that I can notice is that there's a typo in your Path `"C:Temp\Report1.xml"`.

If that does not fix the error, try to change the **type** of `Object` you're creating and use `"microsoft.XMLDOM"` instead.

Updated code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ReportFilename As String
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Dim xmlSourceList As Object

    ReportFilename = "C:\Temp\Report1.xml"

    xmlDoc = CreateObject("microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load(ReportFilename)

    xmlSourceList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DataSource")
    MsgBox(xmlSourceList.length)

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. :) Fixed that.  Result the same. :(

Comment: You're welcome. If that does not fix the error, try to instantiate the object as `"microsoft.XMLDOM"`.

Comment: Result!!  My joy is almost uncontainable!  Thank you so much. :)

Comment: I was sure that was the problem because I had it too. If this answer was helpful, please accept it, so others can benefit from it. :)

Comment: I tried to see if the same thing fixed my MS Access code but sadly it didn't.  I'll have to post that as a new question.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The elements are in a namespace (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition`) so you should use the two-argument form of `getElementsByTagName(uri, localname)` supplying the namespace.